# How to add textPath labels to zoomable sunburst diagram in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have modified [this sunburst diagram in D3](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/477c1bfb081b783f80ad) and would like to add text labels and some other effects. I have tried to adopt every example I could find but without luck. Looks like I'm not quite there yet with D3 :(

For labels, I would like to only use names of top/parent nodes and that they appear outside of the diagram (as per the image below). This doesn't quite work:

```
var label = svg.datum(root)
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(partition.nodes(root).slice(0,3)) // just top/parent nodes?
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("x", 0) // middle of arc
    .attr("dy", -10) // outside last children arcs
    /*
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var angle = (d.x + d.dx / 2) * 180 / Math.PI - 90;
        console.log(d, angle);
        if (Math.floor(angle) == 119) {
            console.log("Flip", d)
            return ""
        } else {
            //return "scale(-1 -1)"
        }
    })
    */
    .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#path_" + i; })
    .text(function(d) { return d.name + " X%"; });
```

I would also like to modify a whole tree branch on hover so that it 'shifts' outwards. How would I accomplish that?

```
function mouseover(d) {
    d3.select(this) // current element and all its children
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); });
        // shift arcs outwards
}
function mouseout(d) {
    d3.selectAll("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("fill", "#fff");
        // bring arcs back
}
```

Next, I'd like to add extra lines/ticks on the outside of the diagram that correspond to boundaries of top/parent nodes, highlighting them. Something along these lines:

```
var ticks = svg.datum(root).selectAll("line")
    .data(partition.nodes)  // just top/parent nodes?
    .enter().append("svg:line")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "#f00");

ticks
    .transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy) + radius/10); });
```

Finally, I would like to limit zoom level so the last nodes in the tree do not fire zoom but instead launch a URL (which will be added in JSON file). How would I modify the below?

```
function click(d) {
    node = d;
    path.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", arcTweenZoom(d));
}
```

[image]

**[My full pen here.](http://codepen.io/znak/pen/MaOdgG)**
Any help with this would be much appreciated.